# Azure AD B2B in Azure Government

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-gov

Is there any way to use Azure AD B2B in Azure Government?

Previously, when I clicked on "New user" and typed in a user from a different tenant (e.g. someguest@someothercompany.com) and it would tell me the users would be added as a guest but unlike Azure AD B2B in Azure commercial, it wouldn't send an email notification.

Now there's a separate "New guest user" button that's grayed out in Azure Government. Are there any conditions under which this button would show enabled? Or is there any other way to add a user from a different Azure AD tenant to my Azure AD Gov tenant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Azure AD B2B is not yet supported in Azure Government**. Support this ask by voting for it in the Azure Government feedback forum: [Azure AD B2B in Azure Government](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/558487-azure-government/suggestions/20588554-azure-ad-b2b-in-azure-government)

Answer (score 0):

Each Azure Gov tenant cannot communicate with each other. You cannot even switch CSPs for your GOV Tenant.

There is kind of a hack for getting this to work.

Create two different AD servers in Azure, then use AD Synce/  Dir Sync with those two different ADs. Then have a site to site VPN to those different Azure ADs.